# MySQL JOIN does not seem to act as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, mysql-workbench

I have the following code in MySQL:

> SELECT *
>
> FROM rbdbase R
>
> JOIN awsectionals A
>
> ON ('A.UNIQUE ID' = 'R.ID');

I am simply trying to join rbdbase and awsectionals together based on UNIQUE ID of awsectionals matching the ID of rbdbase.

If I use JOIN, I get zero results returned.

If I use LEFT JOIN, I get all rows from R with corresponding data from A being NULL
If I use RIGHT JOIN, I get all rows from A with corresponding data from R being NULL

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTYqG.png)

I have checked that there is matching UNIQUE ID and ID from each table. All looks OK.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am expecting a combined table based on matching values for A.UNIQUE ID and R.ID.

Comment: Get rid of the quotes. You're comparing literal strings, not column values.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it hugely. I am currently learning SQL.